# Element form does not need a role attribute

Tags: html5, formularios

¿Tengo una duda de como solucionar un error en W3C?

From line 916, column 9; to line 916, column 124

```
<form role="form" id="widget-subscribe-form" action="../include/subscribe.php" method="post" class="nobottommargin">
```

Answer (score 4):

A pesar de que ya te dieron la solución de como arreglar tu problema. Quiero explicar el atributo `role` en HTML5 para las personas que les pueda interesar que es y para que sirve.

El atributo `role` tiene su origen en el estándar ARIA de accesibilidad web y se ha incorporado también al estándar HTML5. La definición más precisa es la que dan en el [documento oficial](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-role-attribute-20110113/) de HTML5:

> Los atributos "role" permite al creador de una página añadir información a sus documentos HTML que luego puede ser extraída automáticamente por una máquina para obtener información sobre el propósito de cada elemento de la página.

Las personas ciegas y con otros tipos de discapacidad utilizan dispositivos y navegadores especiales. Si una página utiliza los atributos "role" para describir el propósito de cada elemento, la navegación de esas personas será mucho más agradable, ya que su navegador especial es capaz de "entender" cómo está creada la página y puede leer los contenidos al usuario de manera mucho más fácil.

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer el mensaje de error describe el problema:

> El elemento form no necesita un atributo role

Por lo cual quedaría algo así dicha línea

```
<form id="widget-subscribe-form" action="../include/subscribe.php" method="post" class="nobottommargin">
```

Comment: Hola, buenas noches. Es mi primera entrada en está plataforma agredezco mucho la ayuda brindada efectivamente solucione mi error. Espero no afecte a la plantilla. Gracias Shaz.

Comment: @FernandoLopez si consideras que fue útil la respuesta, podrías marcarla como aceptada, haciendo clic en el signo de verificación a la izquierda (cerca al número cero).

Comment: Añado una puntualización. El validador de W3C lo marca como un aviso no como un error, un aviso no significa siempre un fallo. En cualquier caso la documentación sobre ARIA dice: _"Setting an ARIA role and/or aria-* attribute that matches the default implicit ARIA semantics is unnecessary and is NOT RECOMMENDED as these properties are already set by the browser."_
No tiene mucho sentido poner `role=form` en una etiqueta `form` ya que va implícito en ella que es un formulario y los navegadores saben interpretarlo como tal.