# ¿Por qué bootstrap usa role="form" en los formularios?

Tags: html, formularios

Cuando usas `role="form"` en un formulario el validador de W3C, lanza un warning:

> El elemento form no necesita un atributo role

Por ejemplo:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email address:</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

La pregunta se encuentra parcialmente respondida [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/20934/20709).

¿Es esto correcto?, si ***se incorpora para mejorar la accesibilidad*** ¿el problema estaría en el validador W3C?

Comment: Atendiendo a la especificación no hace falta poner a un form el role de form, pero parece ser que algunos lectores, como jaws, lo necesitan para identificar zonas. Quizá tenga más sentido poner el role al grupo de todos los elementos que son parte del formulario, como un título o una descripción que no esté dentro de la etiqueta form, pero no estoy seguro.

Answer (score -1):

Realmente no se debe colocar en el `form`, se deberia colocar en un `div`, porque `form`ya tiene su forma de gestionarse por eso es el error, piensa que necesidad tiene un `form` de tener un role que reafirma lo que ya es. Por lo que realmente no es un problema del validador, la próxima vez intenta ponerlo en un div.